# How can I use capistrano to auto-deploy to a secondary environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I already have a multi-environment capistrato deploy up and working. However, what I would like to do is set it up so that after a deploy to production, capistrano would automatically deploy the same branch to the demo environment. That way, production and demo are always the same code.

Is there a clean/easy way to do this in capistrano? I can currently `cap production deploy` and `cap demo deploy` so I *could* do this via a bash script but I'd rather just have `cap production deploy` deploy to production and then automatically deploy again to demo.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the current cap script sample

Answer (score 1):

You can use the capistrano before/after hooks

```
# call an existing task
before :starting, :ensure_user

after :finishing, :notify


# or define in block
namespace :deploy do
  before :starting, :ensure_user do
    #
  end

  after :finishing, :notify do
    #
  end
end
```

You can define the deployment tasks and then call like this also

```
after 'deploy:finished', 'deploy:staging'
```

Comment: I think this might work just fine. I only want it to do the extra deploy after finishing when deploying to production. That way if I'm deploying to anything else (QA, staging, load, etc) it won't auto-deploy to demo. I think I can figure out how to add that conditional, though

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your multi-environment in config/deploy:

By default, Capistrano runs only one stage at a time. However, if you want to run all stages at once, you can define a custom task that loops through all the stages and deploys to each one in turn.

1. In your Capistrano project, create a file named lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy_all.rake (you may need to create the tasks directory if it doesn't exist yet).
2. In this file, define a custom task that loops through each stage and deploys to it.

   ```
   namespace :deploy do
     desc 'Deploy to all stages'
     task :all do
       stages = %w(production demo) # list all your stage names here
       stages.each do |stage|
         Rake::Task["deploy:#{stage}"].invoke
       end
     end
   end
   ```

In this example, the deploy:all task loops through each stage in the stages array and invokes the corresponding deploy: task for that stage.

Now, to deploy to all stages at once, you can simply run: `cap deploy:all`

Comment: Luis, this is good stuff but not quite what I'm looking for. I want to be able to deploy to production and if it's successful it auto-deploys to demo. This is very useful though because we also have two other environments and there are times when we want to get all of them on the same branch, so your answer is extremely useful in that regard. Thanks!

Comment: One other thing preventing this from working. The second stage starts and I get errors of the type "Capistrano tasks may only be invoked once." because the various sub-tasks were already invoked on the first stage. Not sure if there is a way to reset this or something?